# Replace column values with 0 or 1 based on NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, nan

Here is a snapshot of the CSV data, 
[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knrWp.jpg).

I want to replace the null, or 'nan', values with a 0 and replace all other entries with a 1 in the column 'Death Year':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
mydata_csv = pd.read_csv('D:\Python\character-deaths.csv',sep = ',',encoding = 'utf-8')
mydata_csv
del mydata_csv['Book of Death']
del mydata_csv['Death Chapter']

if mydata_csv['Death Year'] == np.nan:
 mydata_csv['Death Year'] = 0
else:
 mydata_csv['Death Year'] = 1
```

The above code produces the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Very common. What about the other answers that cover this doesn't apply here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36921951/1531971

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. A logical operation on a series/dataframe does not yield a scalar result. It yields a vector, that `if` cannot understand.
2. `NaN != NaN`; your `if` condition will never hold true even if the columns are `NaN`.

   ```
   In [9]: np.nan == np.nan
   Out[9]: False
   ```

---

Just use *`np.where`*.

```
mydata_csv['Death Year'] = np.where(mydata_csv['Death Year'].isnull(), 0, 1)
```

Another improvement I'd recommend is using *`df.drop`* when deleting columns. Instead of `del`, try the more pandaic version:

```
mydata_csv = mydata_csv.drop(['Book of Death', 'Death Chapter'], 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which line, but I suspect that your problem is in

```
if mydata_csv['Death Year'] == np.nan:
```

If so try checking if if the column have data first, something along the lines of

```
if mydata_csv['Death Year'] is not None and mydata_csv['Death Year'] == np.nan:
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This won't help. It is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think better is use [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) for boolean mask and then cast it to `int` -> `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`:

For working with `missing data` is necessary use special functions like `isnull` or `notnull`, check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing) for more information.

```
#omit `sep=','` because default parameter
mydata_csv = pd.read_csv('D:\Python\character-deaths.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
#simplify double del
mydata_csv = mydata_csv.drop(['Book of Death', 'Death Chapter'], axis=1)
mydata_csv['Death Year'] = mydata_csv['Death Year'].notnull().astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
mydata_csv = pd.DataFrame({'Book of Death':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                           'Death Chapter':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                           'Death Year':[np.nan,3,5,np.nan,1,0],
                           'col':[7,8,9,4,2,3]})

print (mydata_csv)   
   Book of Death  Death Chapter  Death Year  col
0              4              7         NaN    7
1              5              8         3.0    8
2              4              9         5.0    9
3              5              4         NaN    4
4              5              2         1.0    2
5              4              3         0.0    3

mydata_csv = mydata_csv.drop(['Book of Death', 'Death Chapter'], axis=1)
mydata_csv['Death Year'] = mydata_csv['Death Year'].notnull().astype(int)
print (mydata_csv)   
   Death Year  col
0           0    7
1           1    8
2           1    9
3           0    4
4           1    2
5           1    3
```

Answer (score 0):

See df.fillna() & df.replace()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html